# HTML5 Image upload and resize on IOS6

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, ios6

I have implemented a way of adding files to a HTML5 app (which IOS6 now allows) and resizing the images before uploading as not to cripple 3G. On chrome running on my Mac everything works fine but when i test in on IOS6 the image is completely squashed and nothing like it should be.

Try this JsFiddle in your browser and mobile browser (IOS6) and it should give you a better idea.

http://jsfiddle.net/Untd8/

Answer (score 3):

See my answer to [HTML5 Canvas drawImage ratio bug iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929099/html5-canvas-drawimage-ratio-bug-ios)

Basically it's a limitation in iOS where JPEGs over 2 megapixels are subsampled.

Comment: Is there a filed bug report for this? Is this a limitation or bug? Is there a ETA on the fix date?