# PhoneGap image rotation issue after transformation

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

We're developing a PhoneGap app that amongst the core features being developed, it also features a user profile section. Within that screen/section we allow the user to update various details including their profile image. The profile image can either be taken with the camera (which works perfectly) or chosen from the users photo library. This is where our issue lies.

We're loading a photo from the users camera or camera roll using the `navigator.camera.getPicture` function.

We then create a new `Image()` and set the `imageURI` returned by phone gap as the image `src`. In the `onload` function of the image we draw the image into a canvas context to resize and crop it into a square.

We had a problem with the image, where when rendering the image was squashed but we've fixed that issue with the help of this post ([HTML5 Canvas drawImage ratio bug iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929099/html5-canvas-drawimage-ratio-bug-ios))

**The Problem:** Everything works well when we get the image directly from the camera but when we set `destinationType` to `navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM` or `navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY` the image comes out rotated incorrectly.

`correctOrientation` *is* set to true.

We're using Cordova 2.8

We can only get image data when the designationType is `FILE_URI` for CAMERA and `NATIVE_URI` for `PHOTOLIBRARY`. Could this difference have something to do with our problem?

The code is:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(function (imageURI) {

context = // 2d context from canvas object in the DOM

base_image = new Image();
base_image.onload = function () {

var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var w = 144;
var h = 144;

... // some size and offset calculations 
var ratio = ... // calculate a ratio based off this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929099/html5-canvas-drawimage-ratio-bug-ios

context.drawImage(base_image, x, y, base_image.width, base_image.height, 0, 0, w, h/ratio);

url = context.canvas.toDataURL().toString();

DOMImage.src = url
}

base_image.src = imageURI;

}, function (error) {
enyo.log("Error " + error);

}, {
    quality : 49,
    targetWidth: 114,
    targetHeight: 114,
    sourceType: sourceType,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    destinationType: destinationType,
    correctOrientation: true,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: false
});
```

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you figure this out ? I'm facing the same problem, cordova 2.9

Answer (score 0):

The image orientation is stored in EXIF data. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600800/js-client-side-exif-orientation-rotate-and-mirror-jpeg-images) you can find the solution to your problem.