# KineticJs: How to scale an Image and keep the position of the attached container?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I have an image (the blue box) and ad red rectangle. The image's offset is set to the center of the image to make rotation around the center of the image. The code is similar to the following:

```
var image = new Kinetic.Image({
x: 200,
y: 100
});
image.offsetX(100);
image.offsetY(50);

var rect = new Kinetic.Rect();

var group = new Kinetic.Group();

group.add(image);
group.add(rect);
layer.add(group);
stage.add(layer);
```

The stage than looks something like this:

[image]

After I rescale the image with

```
image.scaleX(0.5);
image.scaleY(0.5);
```

I get the following:

[image]

The red rectangle is not attached to the image anymore.

I could do

```
rect.scaleX(0.5);
rect.scaleY(0.5);
```

but this would change the size of the rect.

**How do I rescale the image and keep the rectangle attached to the same position as before?**

Edit:

The following image shows what it should look like after the image scaling. Event after the scaling the red rectangle should be attached to the image.

[image]

Comment: Could you describe what you want to happen?  If you want to scale both image and rect while maintaining relative positions you could scale the group that they are both inside.

Comment: @markE I want to scale only the image (blue box). While scaling the image the red box should be attached to the blue box as before.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification -- I understand now...please see my answer for a solution.  Cheers!

Comment: @markE I commented your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the red rect to be centered in the top-left of the blue image after scaling the image, you will need to listen for changes in the images `scaleX` and `scaleY` properties.

You can listen for `scaleX` / `scaleY` property changes like this:

```
image.on("scaleXChange scaleYChange",function(){
    // either scaleX or scaleY has changed on this image
});
```

Then you can reposition the rect to be centered on the images top-left corner like this:

```
image.on("scaleXChange scaleYChange",function(){
    var imgX=this.x()-this.offsetX()*this.scaleX();
    var imgY=this.y()-this.offsetY()*this.scaleY();
    rect.position({x:imgX-rect.width()/2,y:imgY-rect.height()/2});
})
```

Here's a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/6H9aK/

[image][image]

Comment: That work but what if the red rectangle is a group that contains other shapes. Do I have to adjust each shapes position separately? The problem is that group.width() is zero.

Comment: If you want to scale both image and rect while maintaining relative positions you could put both red and blue inside a group and scale that group.

Comment: I don't want to scale the red rectangle. It should only keep the position on the blue rect. The red rect is in a group which contains only the red rectangle. How can you do your solution with the group of the red rectangle instead of the red rect itself?

Comment: OK, if you want the red group to reposition relative to the scaled blue, then you must set a width and height to the red group--no other option.  Then you can use the same code in my answer--just replace rect with red-group.  Cheers!

Comment: thank you. May be you have an idea on this issue too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481870/kineticjs-how-to-import-iphone-retina-images-taken-by-camera

Comment: You're welcome!  I may be the only person in the world who doesn't have an iPhone, but I do know the retina display is 2x the normal. You might check out this set of previous SO answers:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929099/html5-canvas-drawimage-ratio-bug-ios

Comment: I did not see how I can combine this with KineticJs

Comment: Keep in mind that an offscreen html5 canvas can be the source for a Kinetic.Image.  That's how to link the post with KineticJS.  Anyway, like I said, my iPhone knowledge is limited. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Ok thank you! How to I generate a Kinetic Image from a Canvas?

Comment: (1) Get a reference to any canvas element: var canvas=document.getElementById("anyHtmlCanvas"); (2) set the image property on a Kinetic.Image to that reference: var img=new Kinetic.Image({ image: canvas ...

Comment: Your solution in the link also worked. If you post it to my other question I can give you credit for that too.

Comment: Thanks, I'll post on your linked question also...Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead to apply the scaling to both x and y axes at the same time, rather than scaling one first, then the other:

rect.scale({x:0.5,y:0.5});

Comment: I don't think that this would make any difference.

Comment: rect.scale() would scale the rect what I do not want.