# How to fix distortion of large images on iOS devices using fabric.js?

Tags: fabricjs

when I load a large image (> 2 megapixels) on iOS, the image get's distorted when I scale it. There are two fixes out there but I couldn't get them to work because they are not compatible with the way fabric.js handles the canvas element.

Please take a look at the fixes that work for regular (non fabric.js) canvas:

[HTML5 Canvas drawImage ratio bug iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929099/html5-canvas-drawimage-ratio-bug-ios/)

https://github.com/stomita/ios-imagefile-megapixel

Maybe one of you guys can point me in the right direction how to modify the fix so that it works with fabric.js canvas.