# Iphone Image fit Issue in Canvas

Tags: javascript, ios, html, canvas, safari

I am working on HTML5 application for iPhone. Whenever I choose file from take photo option and place it in canvas. It gets squeezed towards top. I am unable to find out the reason.

I have asked this question before and searched many sites but could not find solution of this issue. Any help?

**Demo Image**

Please find [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFW7g.jpg) image to see the issue. Newly taken photo does not occupy space till clear button.

**Html Code:**

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="270" height="300"></canvas>
<input type="file" id="uploadImage" name="upload" value="Upload" onchange="PreviewImage();" />
```

**Javascript Code:**

```
function PreviewImage() {
    var oFReader = new FileReader();
    oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);
    oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 270, 300);
        imageUrl = oFREvent.target.result;
        var base_image = new Image();
        base_image.src = imageUrl;
        base_image.onload = function () {
            ctx.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0, 270, 300);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Do you have some codes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 Canvas drawImage ratio bug iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929099/html5-canvas-drawimage-ratio-bug-ios)

Comment: It's iOS bug/feature. You can fix it, see link before for more info.