# Limit image resolution in HTML5

Tags: html, image

I have been looking at this tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/Camera and implemented the example they have given. It all revolves around this:

```
<input type="file" id="take-picture" accept="image/*">
```

My question is, how can I limit the size of the image? For example, I really just need a thumbnail which I will upload to a server and not a full resolution image. Is it possible to do this or am I stuck with the full sized image? Thank you

Comment: Are you comfortable with any server-side languages? Because that is where this kind of stuff usually happens.

Comment: You should resize image before uploading it not limiting selection big images. This answer may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945494/use-html5-to-resize-an-image-before-upload

Comment: Thanks. I found an answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27897060/html5-camera-api-not-working-in-chrome as well - but that doesn't work in Chrome, do you know why? Firefox is fine... I put it as a separate question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27897060/html5-camera-api-not-working-in-chrome