# resize image before upload javascript

Tags: javascript, image

First, i'm french and i'm sorry in advance for mistakes.
I have a cover photo displayed before sending the form.
The person can reposition the image , zoom , etc.
Script : https://github.com/matiasgagliano/guillotine
[image: exemple in french]

The problem is that i don't know how to send the new image resized and not the default image.
The API has set a function to get info about image :

> var data = picture.guillotine('getData');

but i don't where how use this and where.
I'm a beginner in JS.

Thanks much.

Comment: what have you done so far ?

Comment: Good question. I have not tried yet, but I suggest you look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434458/image-resizing-client-side-with-javascript-before-upload-to-the-server

Comment: and this Q&A also looks promising http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945494/use-html5-to-resize-an-image-before-upload

Comment: @NimS I tried to change value of a hidden input when the image is resized, but doesn't work.

Comment: @fiprojects I will look at this, thks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an idiot.
I put that code into the dragging function.

> var data = picture.guillotine('getData');
>             getID("scale").value = data.scale;
>           getID("x").value = data.x;
>           getID("y").value = data.y;

The values 3 hidden inputs are used to resized the image in PHP with gb librairy