# HTML Post images after resize from jquery with other inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, post

I have used this [git project](https://github.com/joelvardy/javascript-image-upload) to resize images before uploading and in that it post the data as soon as user select the photos. But I want to send(post) those images along with other input fields once the user hit the Submit button. 
So my html code is,

```
  <form  action="process.php" method="post"  id="uploadImageForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload[]" accept="image/jpeg, image/png"  multiple />
        <input type="text" name="Text1">
        -- other input fields --
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
 </form>
```

In the jquery upload function is called for every image

```
 var upload = function (photo, callback) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('photo', photo);
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState === 4) {
            callback(request.response);
        }
    }
    request.open('POST', './process.php');
    request.responseType = 'json';
    request.send(formData);
 };
```

by this function

```
document.querySelector('form input[type=file]').addEventListener('change', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var files = event.target.files;
    for (var i in files) {

        if (typeof files[i] !== 'object') return false;

        (function () {

            var initialSize = files[i].size;

            resize.photo(files[i], 1200, 'file', function (resizedFile) {

                var resizedSize = resizedFile.size;
               // upload happens here, note that upload() is running for each image seperately
                upload(resizedFile, function (response) {
                     //callback function for each upload
                });

            });

        }());

    }

});
```

Please note that the resized images are come to "resizedFile" variable as expected. 
So what I did was append the "resizedFile" variable in to the formData object.

Now I want to send this when submit button clicked along with the other inputs.

Another major issue I'm facing is to take "formData" variable out of the Eventhandler, so that I can try something. So is there a way that I can take this to a global variable? Since in the jquery code i'm using they use 'use strict', can we do that?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945494/use-html5-to-resize-an-image-before-upload) question related to mine, but I couldn't implement that because I dont understand what he ment by "imageResized".

Comment: Where you want to send the other data? TO the same url location?

Comment: To a controller file. Let's say to FileUploadController.php file. FYI I'm using codeignior framework. Thank you.