# Resize & compress uploaded image in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image-resizing, image-compression, hermite

I'm building a website which will have a lot of user uploaded images.
I would like to resize and compress (preferably change their format to .jpg) these images client side, before uploading them to a server.

How would one go about doing this?
I have found a few solutions, but none that really work on uploaded files.
The latest I've tried is the [Hermite-resize](https://github.com/viliusle/Hermite-resize) script. Should be as simple as:

```
// Get images from input field
var uploadedImages = event.currentTarget.files;


var HERMITE = new Hermite_class(); 
HERMITE.resize_image(uploadedImages[1], 300, 100);
```

But apparently the `uploadedImages` return as `null`. While I'm also using them elsewhere, so I'm 100% positive they are not `null`
Does anyone know how to use this script effectively with uploaded files?
Or is there, perhaps, a better solution to resize/compress images on the client side?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a (sort of) solution to my problem. It's not going to be good for everyone, but this guy wrote a little script that is perfect for what I'm trying to accomplish:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39235724/6756447

Works straight out of the box! The only thing I added was to give the returned blob a timestamp and its original name before pushing it to an array:

```
var images = event.currentTarget.files

resizeImage({
   file: images[i],
   maxSize: 500
}).then(function(resizedImage) {
   resizedImage.lastModifiedDate = new Date()
   resizedImage.name = images[i].name
   uploadedImages.push(resizedImage)
}).catch(function(error) {
   console.log(error)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to work on hermite but it is not good class because it gives to me error constantly hence you can use below code, on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4pyy9ksd/), also hermit class wants to img element id

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" id="fileOpload"><br>
<img src="" alt="Image preview..." id="image">
<canvas id="canvas" height=500 width=500></canvas>
```

**Javascript**

```
function previewFile() {
    var preview = document.querySelector('img');
    var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
    var reader  = new FileReader();
    var percentage = 0.75;
        reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
            preview.src = reader.result;
            preview.onload = function () {
                var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                canvas.height = canvas.width * (preview.height / preview.width);
                var oc = document.createElement('canvas'),octx = oc.getContext('2d');
                oc.width = preview.width * percentage;
                oc.height = preview.height * percentage;
                canvas.width = oc.width;
                canvas.height = oc.height;
                octx.drawImage(preview, 0, 0, oc.width, oc.height);
                octx.drawImage(oc, 0, 0, oc.width, oc.height);
                ctx.drawImage(oc, 0, 0, oc.width, oc.height,0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            }
        }, false);

    if (file) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}
document.getElementById('fileOpload').addEventListener('change', previewFile);
```