# How to resize the image in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I upload image from nodejs to vue 
And put the image in v-card

But the image is cut off

how to resize the image by not cutting?

Answer (score 21):

Use 'contain' attribute in v-img

```
<v-img src="/picture.png" alt=""
    contain    <!-- causes picture not to be cropped -->
    height="100px"
    width="150px">
</v-img>
```

check https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/images#api for more information

Answer (score 14):

I understand this question has been answered long back but adding my answer to help the community.

The code below is not specific just for `vuetify.js` but this can also be used in any `vue.js` projects - just change the markups. And if you modify a bit then this can also be used in React, Angular or any JS frameworks.

```js
// If you like - you can move this section into separate file 
// ------- Move from here -------
const dataURItoBlob = (dataURI) => {
  const bytes = dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0
    ? atob(dataURI.split(',')[1])
    : unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
  const mime = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];
  const max = bytes.length;
  const ia = new Uint8Array(max);
  for (let i = 0; i < max; i += 1) ia[i] = bytes.charCodeAt(i);
  return new Blob([ia], { type: mime });
};

const resizeImage = ({ file, maxSize }) => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  const image = new Image();
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

  const resize = () => {
    let { width, height } = image;

    if (width > height) {
      if (width > maxSize) {
        height *= maxSize / width;
        width = maxSize;
      }
    } else if (height > maxSize) {
      width *= maxSize / height;
      height = maxSize;
    }

    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);

    const dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');

    return dataURItoBlob(dataUrl);
  };

  return new Promise((ok, no) => {
    if (!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
      no(new Error('Not an image'));
      return;
    }

    reader.onload = (readerEvent) => {
      image.onload = () => ok(resize());
      image.src = readerEvent.target.result;
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
};

// export default resizeImage; // uncomment once moved to resizeImage.js
// ------- till here - into ./src/plugins/image-resize.js -------

// And then import in whichever component you like in this way:
// import resizeImage from '@/plugins/image-resize.js';

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      originalImg: '',
      resizedImg: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    readURL(file) {
      // START: preview original
      // you can remove this section if you don't like to preview original image
      if (!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
        no(new Error('Not an image'));
        return;
      }

      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (e) => this.originalImg = e.target.result;
      reader.readAsDataURL(file); // convert to base64 string
      // END: preview original

      // START: preview resized
      resizeImage({ file: file, maxSize: 150 }).then((resizedImage) => {
        this.resizedImg = URL.createObjectURL(resizedImage);
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
      // END: preview resized
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        <v-file-input
          accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/bmp"
          placeholder="Pick an Image"
          prepend-icon="mdi-camera"
          label="Avatar"
          @change="readURL"
        ></v-file-input>
      </v-container>

      <v-container v-if="originalImg">
        <v-row justify="space-around">
          <v-col cols="5">
            <div class="subheading">Original Image</div>
            <img :src="originalImg"/>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="5">
            <div class="subheading">Resized Image</div>
            <img :src="resizedImg"/>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answers that helped me to complete this answer:

1. [Preview an image before it is uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4459419/1292050)
2. [Use HTML5 to resize an image before upload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39235724/1292050)

Comment: neat solution +1

Comment: @SantiagoHernández, Just in case if you like to further refactor, you can save 3 lines in your code by destructuring `resizeImage = ({ file, maxSize })` and `let { width, height } = image`

Comment: thank you for sharing your solution! I had to change one thing to make it work: as it was unclear for me, where the `file` parameter in `readUrl()` came from, I decided to use `refs()` (somewhat like here: https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/vue/file). Additionally I removed the redundant file type check, but other than that great work!