# How to resize image - and keep transparent background

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39235724/3683643) to resize images. The resize works just fine, except the image background changes from transparent to black. I would like to maintain the transparent background but haven't found a resource explaining how to do it.

https://jsfiddle.net/skwny/gh7c2mpa/

`see fiddle`

Comment: Please provide a working example of your own code and not just a link to some other page with someone else's code.

Comment: @jered updated with fiddle

Comment: I think all you need to do is make it `image/png` and you should be good

Comment: @joyBlanks you nailed it - thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For image transparency, you need a proper image format change `image/jpeg` to `image/png`

```
var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
```

Comment: A little more detail, any extension can be used as long as it's the same as the original file.