# How to correct image orientation on this function?

Tags: javascript, image, orientation

How is it possible to correct image orientation on this answer
[Use HTML5 to resize an image before upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945494/use-html5-to-resize-an-image-before-upload)

I use this function to resize images on client before uploading to server. If I upload image from mobile phone image is saved in wrong orientation. I want to correct orientation client side before upload?

Comment: *If I upload image from mobile phone image is saved in wrong orientation.* Why not just change the orientation of the picture on your phone and re-upload it?

Comment: I found these functions https://stackoverflow.com/a/40867559/10815299 (to change orientation) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/32490603/10815299 (to get orientation of uploaded image) who seems to solve my problem, but how to combine?