# How to rescale Image to 12 x 12 Automatically whenever someone select a file from computer <input type="file" name="image[]" class="box_file" />

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, html5-canvas

My Goal is to rescale the image automatically to 12 x 12 whenever someone select the file from desktop. Eg: - If user select 1000 x 500 image i want it to automatically rescale to 12 x 12

HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" class="myimage" />
```

(Using Javascript)

Comment: What do you mean by rescaling the image to 12 x 12? What code have you already tried? Please clarify your question.

Comment: if someone select thumbnail size image i want it to automatically convert to icon size (12 x 12) height and width

Comment: do you mean 12px x 12px, of height and width, that may be very small right?

Comment: 12 x 12 was just a random number....

Comment: refer this answer,it is helpful and is the same ,https://stackoverflow.com/a/24015367/12793212

Comment: its not not working....

Comment: Please check my answer, is that what you are looking to do?

Comment: I've updated my code, this should completely resolve your problem. Please take a look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the image to have a certain dimensions such as 12x12 as soon as it loads, you will need to add a class to the image by listening to the 'load' event of the image. Like this:

The class will be applied as soon as the image is loaded from desktop, and within this class you will specify your required dimensions.

**EDIT:**
I have updated my post as per your comment. Please make sure to specify these important details in the question itself while asking in the future.

Run the below code snippet and upload any sized image but when it loads here it will have 100px x 100px.

```js
const input = document.querySelector(".myimage");

input.addEventListener("change", function () {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
      document.querySelector("img").src = e.target.result;
      document.querySelector("img").classList.add("rescale-img");
    });
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
});
```

```css
.rescale-img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    }
```

```html
<input type="file" name="files" class="myimage" /> 
<img src="#">
```

Comment: yes this is what i wanted...... but not on click but automatically

Comment: Yes, I've made changes for that, Please check the answer now

Comment: User ---> Select File From Computer ----> File Automatically Rescaled to desired length and width,

Comment: but it has one disadvantage that, the whole image is not resized to the 12px x 12px, but it is cropped and resized,

what if we want the whole image to be resized to the 12px x 12px, without losing anything from the image, like not a crop method.

Comment: It is not cropped, this is the original image: https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/389/mitze-1380778.jpg The aspect ratio and the contents are intact, not cropped.

Comment: ok thankyou, i also wanted to make this kind of code, for resizing, as it was a problem in one of my app. thankyou very much.

Comment: <input type="file" name="files[]" class="myimage" /> this is my input form.......  please change the above code according to it.......

Comment: try now, click on button, select any large sized image, it will automatically rescale as it loads.

Comment: Please make sure to add these important details to the question itself instead of comments in the future, hope this resolves your problem

Comment: your code alone is working properly........ but not with my web app......

Comment: That means you are either integrating my code into your app wrong, or there is something else that is wrong in your code. Sorry, but I will not be able to help with that via stack overflow. Hope you'll find a way to make my code work in your app.

Comment: it is only working in web page.....but when i download the resize image it still show the original size......

Comment: Yes, that is because that is how JS, HTML Elements and DOM work. You cannot just change the dimensions of the original image without some external library using vanilla Javascript. You can only edit how stuff looks on your webpage, JS is limited to a webpage, it is not a photo editing tool.

Comment: Maybe you can use a library such as : compress.js https://www.npmjs.com/package/compress.js

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:

```js
function activate() {
  document.getElementById("image").style.width = "12rem"
  document.getElementById("image").style.height = "12rem"
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/95/Test_image.jpg" id="image"></img>
<button onclick="activate()">Activate small thingy</button>
```

Edit the size to your liking, but 12px is too small.