# How to resize an image using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an image with a size of around 12MB and it takes time to get loaded. Is there any way to reduce the size of the image to make it load faster? Thanks

New Update:
I want to reduce the image size as it gets loaded from an input type file.

Comment: If you dont mind the manual step, you can just use this: https://tiny-img.com/

Comment: You're going to need to compress the image. Use something like [imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php)

Comment: Cannot resize what you have not loaded, so unless you're planning to resize on the backend, the answer is no.

Comment: Or use something like [sharp](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/) to do it programmatically.

Comment: you want to do this in javascript in the browser?

Comment: @Bravo yes, i want to do that on the browser. I have an image which get loads from an input type file. It takes too long because of its size.

Comment: Is there a way to upload only every 16th pixel only from a file? That would function as resizing.

Comment: @MauriceNino I won't be able to use `tiny-img.com` because the images get loaded from an input type file. also for `sharp` because this issue will be implemented in an old technology application that uses only `JavaScript`.

Comment: Well, your frontend JavaScript will not be able to resize the image to reduce load. If you do not run NodeJS in your backend, then the question should probably be asked with another tag.

Comment: And if you want to resize the image *on upload*, you should specify that in the question.

Comment: Great. Here is a native JS solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24015367/9150652. And here is a module that can do it for you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pica (although there are probably many others that do a similar thing).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to load images using `Image()` js method so the remaning content of the page load properly, and use `loading = 'lazy'` property on the images to make the browser load them only when they are visible in the viewport or when you scroll near to them.

```js
function loadImg(){
var img = new Image(400, 400);
img.src = 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1220067947798024192/30eZhfxx_400x400.png';
img.setAttribute("loading", "lazy")
document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

```css
#btn{
position: fixed;
top: 5px
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="loadImg()" value="Load image" id="btn">
```

Comment: it keeps creating new images every time I click on the `load image` button

Comment: thats the purpose of the snippet above, its just an exemple, try use `loading = 'lazy'` in your code