# Image Upload - Resize on Client Side piror to ajax call to php server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I have been doing research for quite a while already about this problem, and still haven't figure out the best way to resize the image prior to sending it to my Apache server via ajax.

I am trying to use the html5 canvas approach mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333971/html5-pre-resize-images-before-uploading)

But I am having a hard time trying to work with the line:

```
var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

I would like to pass it to my server like a normal image file, so that in php i can call the follow code like `$_FILES['file']['error']` 
to check the size, type, duplicate, etc... (just like how i would normally go about uploading the image) 
Most importantly, I would like to use move_uploaded_file function in php to upload those image to server.

However, using the html5 canvas resize approach, I can no longer do so, since after decoding and trimming out the header part of the canvas.toDataURL, I am left with just a image itself to work with in my php code.

```
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'uploads/');
    $img = $_POST['image'];
    $img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $img);
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
    $data = base64_decode($img);
    $file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.jpg';
    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
    print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
```

Any other approach to achieve this action without the HTML5 canvas?

(Bottom line: I don't have any luck merging the traditional upload image with the new html5 canvas image resize technique)

Comment: Why not just create an image resource from the base64 encoded string, eg ~ `$img = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($string))`. From there you can get all sorts of data about the image

Comment: Any example please? So I will pass my $img inside my ajax call to my php server?