# How to input an image and use that as the cursor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms

I am trying to make a cursor changer, where the user can upload an image, and it will be the cursor anywhere on the document `<body>`. However it doesn't seem to work. I have tried `.append` and `.appendChild`, but it doesn't seem to work. Where have I gone wrong?

```js
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#uploaded1').attr('src', e.target.result);
        $("#upload-cursor").css("display", "block");
        $("#upload-cursor").click(function() {

              $("body").css("cursor", "url(" + e.target.result + "), auto");
          
        });
    };
    
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h5>Upload Cursor</h5>
<form runat="server">
  <input type='file' id="imgInp">
    <img id="uploaded1" src="#" width="50px" height="50px">
    <br>
</form>
<button id="upload-cursor" style="display: none;">Create Cursor</button>
```

Comment: Not all browsers support all image formats, and the maximum size the image can have, might be limited as well - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Basic_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property#Limitations

Comment: Your code worked fine for me - I saved SO's favicon.ico, selected that that and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the above answer, you image size might be big so do resize the Image.

to resize use the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications), then you can process the images with the [canvas element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images).

This [Mozilla Hacks blog post](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/01/how-to-develop-a-html5-image-uploader/) walks you through most of the process. For reference here's the assembled source code from the blog post:

```js
// from an input element
var filesToUpload = input.files;
var file = filesToUpload[0];

var img = document.createElement("img");
var reader = new FileReader();  
reader.onload = function(e) {img.src = e.target.result}
reader.readAsDataURL(file);

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

var MAX_WIDTH = 800;
var MAX_HEIGHT = 600;
var width = img.width;
var height = img.height;

if (width > height) {
    if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
        height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
        width = MAX_WIDTH;
    }
} 
else {
    if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
        width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
        height = MAX_HEIGHT;
    }
}

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

//Post dataurl to the server with AJAX
```

Resizing before uploading:

> [HTML5 Pre-resize images before uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333971/html5-pre-resize-images-before-uploading)